# Modal dialog of the url not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Sorry this is driving me nuts but my modal dialog box is not showing up when I switch button to a link.  Basically for this functionality (sorry I had to take company sensitive data out so some of the code is missing but still works) I just want the editors to put in a link with an id or class and that link doesn't work but the address opens a dialog box with the address url in it.

I have this working with a button but this does not work with a link and code below.  Also they are manually entering link into p-tag and wondering if it can be captured via href.

```
$(function() {
    var dialog, form,


      tips = $( ".validateTips" );


    function addUser() {
      var valid = true;
      allFields.removeClass( "ui-state-error" );

      valid = valid && checkLength( name, "username", 3, 16 );
      valid = valid && checkLength( email, "email", 6, 80 );
      valid = valid && checkLength( password, "password", 5, 16 );

      valid = valid && checkRegexp( name, /^[a-z]([0-9a-z_\s])+$/i, "Username may consist of a-z, 0-9, underscores, spaces and must begin with a letter." );
      valid = valid && checkRegexp( email, emailRegex, "eg. ui@jquery.com" );
      valid = valid && checkRegexp( password, /^([0-9a-zA-Z])+$/, "Password field only allow : a-z 0-9" );

      if ( valid ) {
        $( "#users tbody" ).append( "<tr>" +
          "<td>" + name.val() + "</td>" +
          "<td>" + email.val() + "</td>" +
          "<td>" + password.val() + "</td>" +
        "</tr>" );
        dialog.dialog( "close" );
      }
      return valid;
    }

    dialog = $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
      height: 300,
      width: 350,
      modal: true,

    });

    form = dialog.find( "form" ).on( "submit", function( event ) {
      event.preventDefault();
      addUser();
    });

    $( "#create-link" ).a().on( "click", function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      dialog.dialog( "open" );
    });
  });



<div><a href="https://xyz" id="create-link">Perma-link</a></div>
<div id="dialog-form" title="Link Address">
<p class="validateTips">https://xyz</p>
</div>
```

Note - I completely understand that it is odd to capture a link in a modal box but we must do this because the vendor does not display the full active link in the url.  So when our users try to share the page they copy the url in browser which takes other users no where.  The link here takes them to the permanent page.  I know this is stupid but needed.

Comment: Are you using jQueryUI? Might want to add that tag.

Comment: @benjarwar - added.  I don't want to be version specific because I can switch.

Comment: Sure, but $.dialog() is not a function in the standard jQuery library. Are you sure you have jQueryUI loaded on your page?

Comment: @benjarwar - it is loaded.  This works fine when I change out the links and put in buttons.

Comment: What is `.a()` in `$( "#create-link" ).a()`? Pretty sure the method a() is not any form of jquery or jquery UI method.

Comment: @Tom - my attempt to change button to link.  Obviously a wrong attempt?  I changed out the word button for a and then changed html...

Comment: @blankip Why would you change that? `click` event would work on a button right?

Comment: @SudhansuChoudhary - the UI guys wanted me to hand it over as a link.   So the last part of this was moving the button to a link and then making the href automatically populate the validateTips section.

Comment: I see what you did there. There was a `.button()` call to [the JQuery UI Button plugin](https://jqueryui.com/button/) and you changed it to `a()`... Just remove it.

Answer (score 1):

When you look up an element with a jQuery selector, it returns a jQuery object that you can call jQuery defined methods on.

In your code, you have:

```
$( "#create-link" ).a().on( "click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  dialog.dialog( "open" );
});
```

The object returned by `$("#create-link")` is a jQuery object of the `a` tag in your html. You can only call jQuery methods on that object. The method `a()` is not defined as far as I know in jQuery or jQuery UI. Remove that.

As for the link itself, it doesn't make sense to add a link and then block the action of clicking the link. I'm guessing you aren't understanding the requirements, based on this comment:

> the UI guys wanted me to hand it over as a link. So the last part of
>   this was moving the button to a link and then making the href
>   automatically populate the validateTips section

That reads to me like they want you to provide the user with a link.

Comment: The UI guys want a link that opens the dialog box with the link address in there so people can copy/paste it.  It is really odd and special for a crappy vendor we deal with.  So a link that opens just a dialog to the link text - not the link working.

Comment: That did work and was simple.  Is there a way I can take the href value and display it?

Comment: @blankip You could set it back to a button and consider using a data attribute or other method (like a hidden input) of passing the link along to the dialog.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think your click event is firing when you click the link. Why not say

```
$( "#create-link" ).on( "click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  dialog.dialog( "open" );
});
```

Simply removing the a(). should fix things.

See here http://jsfiddle.net/eos4c25w/1/

Comment: This worked.  Is there a way to auto display the href content of #create-link?

Comment: var href = $('#create-link').attr('href');

Comment: You can then append it to the page using jQuery append http://api.jquery.com/append/

Comment: When I use the second code it gave me just a "1" in my dialog box.  Testing on our site it just takes you to the link.

Comment: You have two answers here to your original question. I think you should select one of them as the correct answer to this thread.

Comment: In response to your second question, you need to be more clear about what you trying to achieve, You should do this as a new thread.